# sequencing async/await calls in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, async-await, ecmascript-2016

I have the following code snippet.I am facing a problem that sometimes the sequence is not honored i.e _doSomethingNext( )is called before _doSomethingFirst( ).

```
<CustomModal
  onDissmiss( ): { ( )=> { 
     executeInSequence( );
  }
}
/>
private executeInSequence( ):void {
   this._fun1( ).then(( ) => { this._fun2(); });
} 
private async _fun1( ):void {
  const result: IResultArray[] = await httpClient1.getData ();
    if (!result) {
        this._doSomethingFirst();
    }
}
private async _fun2( ):void {
  const result: IResultArray[] = await httpClient2.getData ();
    if (!result) {
        this._doSomethingNext();
    }
}
```

Any idea why is this happening and how do I ensure sequence and only single call to await calls to getData( ).

Comment: Might be because you're not returning anything from `_fun1` or `_fun2`?

Comment: _fun1 and _fun2 also need to be `async` functions for you to be able to use the `await` keyword

Comment: @AluanHaddad It absolutely is true. You cannot use the `await` keyword inside of a function that is not declared as `async`, as it will cause a syntax error. I'm not sure where you're getting your information from, but please read up some more

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. For some reason I thought you were saying that only async functions can be awaited

Comment: @AluanHaddad that makes more sense, sorry to respond so harshly but it wouldn't be good if someone were to read that and then start trying to use `await` in functions not declared as `async`

Comment: Not at all. I would have responded the same way

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo have corrected this now in the query.. the functions have been defined with async keyword but still, they are not running in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You should have return statements and async keyword like this;

```
private async _fun1( ) {
  const result: IResultArray[] = await httpClient1.getData ();
    if (!result) {
        return this._doSomethingFirst();
    }
}

private async _fun2( ) {
  const result: IResultArray[] = await httpClient2.getData ();
    if (!result) {
        return this._doSomethingNext();
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume the code snippet is valid even if fun1(), doSomethingFirst() and doSomethingNext() are all declared with void return type.

Comment: I missed the void return type @Tarun, I will change